# java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology.getYear(BasicChronology.java:426)

Tags: java, stack-overflow, jodatime, joda-convert

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong for getting this StackOverFlowError with Joda library?

Here the code implyed:

```
  public Integer getAge() {
    if ( getBirthDate() != "//" ) {
        try {
            LocalDate birth = LocalDate.parse( getBirthDate(), DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" ) );//Error raised here
            DateTime today = new DateTime();
            if ( today.getMonthOfYear() >= birth.getMonthOfYear() ) {
                age = today.getYear() - birth.getYear();
            } else {
                age = today.getYear() - birth.getYear() - 1;
            }
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return age;
}
```

Here where I call this method :

```
@Override
public boolean equals( Object obj ) {

    if ( this == obj ) {
        return true;
    }
    if ( obj == null ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( !( obj instanceof Identite ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    Identity other = (Identity) obj;
    EqualsBuilder equalsBuilder = new EqualsBuilder();

    equalsBuilder.append( getAge(), other.getAge() );//here the call
    return equalsBuilder.isEquals();
}
```

I am using the getter method for Hibernate.

How to avoid this error?

The stack trace :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicChronology.getYear(BasicChronology.java:426)
at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicGJChronology.setYear(BasicGJChronology.java:180)
at org.joda.time.chrono.BasicYearDateTimeField.setExtended(BasicYearDateTimeField.java:92)
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket$SavedField.set(DateTimeParserBucket.java:568)
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:447)
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.computeMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:411)
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:887)
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate(DateTimeFormatter.java:844)
at org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:179)
at com.home.entities.Identity.getAge(Identite.java:127)
at com.home.entities.Identity.equals(Identite.java:185)
```

**EDIT** Joda dependencies and getBirthDate():

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
       <version>2.9.7</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

The method is:

```
public String getBirthDate() {
    if ( getBirthDay() != null && getBirthMonth() != null && getBirthYear() != null ) {
        birthDate= getBirthDay()+ "/" +  getBirthMonth() + "/" + getBirthYear();
    }
    return birthDate;
}
```

Comment: wasn't joda time implemented in java 1.7?

Comment: What does `getBirthDate()` yield as string? @XtremeBaumer No Joda-Time is not part of Java, but in Java-8 a new time library `java.time`-package was introduced mainly by the same author (of Joda-Time) inspired by Joda-Time. However, both libs are very different.

Comment: @Meno Hochschild yes getBirthDate() is a string wich contains "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Are you sure, the pattern itself and not the textual date???

Comment: Share the code of `getBirthDate()` method

Comment: @akuma8 You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: One thing is clear: If `getBirthDate()` really contains the string "dd/mm/yyyy" then we get this exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "dd/mm/yyyy"` but not a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: I added the `getBirthDate()` method. The field concerned are simple string.

Comment: Hm, my suspicion is: The `StackOverflowError` might not be directly related to Joda-Time but was just due to the fact that some internal stack depth in the JVM was exhausted. This can happen if an app has extremely many layers of invocation.

Comment: I'll dig the problem I'll let you know.

Comment: It's not the question's topic, but to calculate a difference in years you can use `org.joda.time.Years` class and call `Years.yearsBetween(birth, new LocalDate()).getYears()` to get the number of years

Comment: @Hugo I will think abut your suggestion next time. I don't know methods offered by this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of this exception, I just forgot to load the required data from database.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DateTime birth = new DateTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(getBirthDate()));
```

This assumes that getBirthDate() returns the date in the form anticipated in your DateTimeFormat.forPattern() of "dd/MM/yyyy"  for example "11/04/2017"

If you must use DateTimeFormatter try this:

```
 DateTime birth = new DateTime(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").parseDateTime(birthdate));
```

Comment: Have you tested your proposal ? You don't even know what `getBirthDate()` yields. And the question is about Joda-Time, not `SimpleDateFormat`.